# Div inside a div has a top margin which I cannot figure out how to remove

Tags: html, css

I'm new to HTML and CSS and have been following a course on them. One of the objectives was to try to make a rough basic copy of the visuals of any website we'd like in order to practice what we learned - so I picked the Gitlab front page.

Was progressing fine until I reached this 'Get Free Trial' div. My idea was to set the Get Free Trial div inside the outer div and center it. No matter what I do, however, there is always this margin/padding from the top that I can't get rid of and I have no idea why it is there.

```css
#topbar {
  height: 68px;
}

#adbar {
  background-color: #9B51E0;
  height: 60px;
}

#main {
  background-color: white;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#logo-div {
  height: 68px;
  width: 155px;
  float: left;
}

#logo {
  margin: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  width: 108px;
}

.menu-div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 68px;
  float: left;
}

.menu-text {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 90%;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #929292;
  margin-top: 27px;
}

.menu-text:hover {
  color: #9B51E0;
}

#search-div {
  width: 530px;
  float: left;
  height: 68px;
}

#search {
  float: right;
  width: 13px;
  margin-right: 25px;
  margin-top: 25px;
}

#trial-div {
  width: 140px;
  background-color: burlywood;
  float: left;
  height: 68px;
}

#trial-button {
  height: 70%;
  width: 90%;
  background-color: #FA7035;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 10%;
}

#trial-text {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 90%;
  font-family: Arial;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div id="topbar">
  <div id="logo-div">
    <img src="logo2.PNG" id="logo">
  </div>
  <div class="menu-div">
    <p class="menu-text">Product</p>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-div">
    <p class="menu-text">Solutions</p>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-div">
    <p class="menu-text">Resources</p>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-div">
    <p class="menu-text">Partners</p>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-div">
    <p class="menu-text">Pricing</p>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-div">
    <p class="menu-text">Support</p>
  </div>

  <div id="search-div">
    <img src="search.png" id="search">
  </div>

  <div id="trial-div">
    <div id="trial-button">
      <p id="trial-text">Get free trial</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="adbar">

</div>

<div id="main">

</div>
```

Any ideas and could I ask for an explanation of why this happens? Thank you!

Comment: use the web browser inspector and you'll see where the margin it's coming from!

Comment: As @ASG said, the inspector is your friend. From the code you supplied, I can't tell what your problem is. There's no obvious margin on the elements you described, but there is a visible border around the button. If that's what you mean, it comes from the fact that you've set the width and height to 90% and 70%, respectively. Set them to 100% and the button should fill the parent div.

Comment: You should use flexbox or grid for making navbar design.

Comment: @JohnP if I change them to 100% it still has a margin from the top, no idea why. In theory it shouldn't have - also what can I do with the inspector?

Comment: Can you describe exactly where this margin is (e.g. an annotated image)? Because, as I say, from the code you shared, I can't tell quite what you mean.

Comment: @JohnP https://imgur.com/a/bF28JJQ here are two screenshots of how it looks like

Answer (score 0):

**If your final goal is to center the inner div (get free trial) inside outer div:**

`<div id="trial-div" style="display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:center;">`

```css
#topbar {
  height: 68px;
}

#adbar {
  background-color: #9B51E0;
  height: 60px;
}

#main {
  background-color: white;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#logo-div {
  height: 68px;
  width: 155px;
  float: left;
}

#logo {
  margin: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  width: 108px;
}

.menu-div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 68px;
  float: left;
}

.menu-text {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 90%;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #929292;
  margin-top: 27px;
}

.menu-text:hover {
  color: #9B51E0;
}

#search-div {
  width: 530px;
  float: left;
  height: 68px;
}

#search {
  float: right;
  width: 13px;
  margin-right: 25px;
  margin-top: 25px;
}

#trial-div {
  width: 140px;
  background-color: burlywood;
  float: left;
  height: 68px;
}

#trial-button {
  height: 70%;
  width: 90%;
  background-color: #FA7035;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 10%;
}

#trial-text {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 90%;
  font-family: Arial;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div id="topbar">
  <div id="logo-div">
    <img src="logo2.PNG" id="logo">
  </div>
  <div class="menu-div">
    <p class="menu-text">Product</p>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-div">
    <p class="menu-text">Solutions</p>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-div">
    <p class="menu-text">Resources</p>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-div">
    <p class="menu-text">Partners</p>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-div">
    <p class="menu-text">Pricing</p>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-div">
    <p class="menu-text">Support</p>
  </div>

  <div id="search-div">
    <img src="search.png" id="search">
  </div>

  <div id="trial-div" style="display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:center;">
    <div id="trial-button">
      <p id="trial-text">Get free trial</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="adbar">

</div>

<div id="main">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without being able to see everything, did you reset the styles from the browser? Each browser comes with a built in style sheet that has padding and margins. I recommend loading a reset.css stylesheet BEFORE your actual stylesheet. This will clear all browser styles. Make sure yours is second otherwise the reset will override yours.

Here is the reset styles I use:
https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, it was the CSS code in my trial-text id. Putting margins there sets a margin in relation to the trial-div div and not the trial-button div. This forces the trial-button div to also apply a margin.

Not sure why exactly this happens and it doesnt apply a margin to the trial-button div though